# Binding a listbox inside a custom control .Cannot Bind it

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Binding a listbox inside a custom control

I am building a custom control which will have a listbox inside.I have posted here the simplified version

I cannot seem to be displaying a property of my bound viewModel."Surname".

Could you see what I am doing wrong?

Generic.Xaml (inside CustomControl)

```
        <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1.SimpleList">
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleListControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleListControl}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                            <Grid ShowGridLines="False" 
                                  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                                                        FindAncestor, 
                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type local:SimpleListControl}}}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <ListBox Name="lstLeft" 
                                              MinHeight="200"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding LeftSideList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                              DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayMemberPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                              SelectionMode="Extended"
                                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                              SelectedIndex="0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>


        public class SimpleListControl : Control
        {
            static SimpleListControl()
            {
                DefaultStyleKeyProperty
                    .OverrideMetadata(typeof(SimpleListControl), 
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SimpleListControl)));

                LeftSideListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LeftSideList", 
                    typeof(IEnumerable), 
                    typeof(SimpleListControl), 
                    new PropertyMetadata(OnLeftItemsSourceChanged));

                DisplayMemberPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", 
                    typeof(string), 
                    typeof(SimpleListControl), 
                    new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
            }


            public readonly static DependencyProperty LeftSideListProperty;
            public ObservableCollection<object> LeftSideList
            {
                get{return new ObservableCollection<object>{GetValue(LeftSideListProperty)};}
                set { SetValue(LeftSideListProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty;
            public string DisplayMemberPath
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
                set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
            }

            private static void OnLeftItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                //TODO.
            }
        }
```

CustomerView

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Views.CustomersView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:simpleList="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1.SimpleList;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels"
        Title="CustomersViewq" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModels:CustomersViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <simpleList:SimpleListControl Name="SimpleListControl1" 
                                LeftSideList="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Path=AvailableCustomers}"
                               DisplayMemberPath="Surname" Margin="0,24,0,12" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CustomersViewModel

```
public class CustomersViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
    public CustomersViewModel()
    {
        availableCustomers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>();
        availableCustomers.Add(new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Jo1", Surname = "Bloggs1" });
        availableCustomers.Add(new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Jo2", Surname = "Bloggs2" });
        availableCustomers.Add(new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Jo3", Surname = "Bloggs3" });
        availableCustomers.Add(new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Jo4", Surname = "Bloggs4" });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> availableCustomers;

    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> AvailableCustomers
    {
        get { return availableCustomers; }
        set
        {
            if (availableCustomers == value) return;
            availableCustomers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AvailableCustomers");
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerViewModel

```
 public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (firstName == null) return;
            firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string surname;

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set
        {
            if (surname == null) return;
            surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you trying to achieve, it seems you are over complicating things. 
However if you need to display `Surname` you need to set it in the `DisplayMemberPath` as `DisplayMemberPath="Surname"`.
Here's a tutorial on Custom Controls: [How to Create Custom Control](http://www.wpftutorial.net/howtocreateacustomcontrol.html).

Below is a link for creating re-useable User control:
[Creating Re-useable User Controls](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply.That was a typo it does not work by setting "Surname" that is what is baffling. Regarding the complexity . I would you simplify it? The requirement is to create  a wpf customControl that will have listbox  + some buttons and this custom control will be referenced by different wpf application .

Comment: I would recommend you go with creating a `User Control` instead unless if you have requirements not met by `User Control`.

Comment: i have already seen those links and they did not help.I missing something trivial and I cannot see it.Frustrating.I have been told to create a customcontrols this will be inside a dll bit like the "wpfToolkit"if you like. Anybody any suggestions?